# Where's the install location of the ROS indigo's opencv

Tags: opencv

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, all,

My OS is ubuntu 14.04, I had installed ROS indigo (Desktop-Full), where's the install location of the ROS indigo's opencv ?
I  coudn't find it in "/opt/ros/indigo/lib"

Could somebody answer me?

THX~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/222823/where%27s-the-install-location-of-the-ros-indigo%27s-opencv/) by [Milton](https://answers.ros.org/users/21140/milton/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2015-12-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Opencv is separate to ros but will have been installed because ros is dependant upon it.

On Linux it should have been installed to /usr/include/opencv /usr/include/opencv2 for includes  /usr/bin and /usr/lib for binaries and libraries.

Hope this helps

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2015-12-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0